# Meaning of coinvariants of a comodule

Tags: coalgebras, comodules, bialgebras

Let $M$ be a comodule over the bialgebra $B$, with structure map $\rho:M \to M \otimes B$. The space of coinvariants is defined as $M^{coB}:=\{m \in M~|~\rho(m)=m\otimes 1_B\}$. A book I'm reading calls this "the space of generators" of $M$. I wonder what's the motivation of this naming. How does $M^{coB}$ "generate" $M$?

I know that if $M$ is a free comodule genetared by $X$, that is, $M=X\otimes{B}$, then $M^{coB}=X$, so $M$ is indeed generated by $M^{coB}$. Do we have a similar result for general comodules?

Answer (score 7):

If $H$ is a $\Bbbk$-Hopf algebra ($\Bbbk$ a field), then for every $H$-Hopf module $M$ you have an isomorphism of Hopf modules $M\cong M^{coH}\otimes H$.

In fact, this is an equivalence and it is known as the structure theorem for Hopf modules: if we denote by $\mathfrak{M}$ the category of $\Bbbk$-vector spaces and by $\mathfrak{M}_B^B$ the category of Hopf modules over a bialgebra $B$ then we have an adjunction with left and right adjoint $-\otimes B:\mathfrak{M}\to\mathfrak{M}_B^B$ and $(-)^{coB}:\mathfrak{M}_B^B\to\mathfrak{M}$ respectively. This adjunction is an equivalence if and only if $B$ is a Hopf algebra.

This may justify why your reference calls this "the space of generators". However, it may be useful if you explicitly mention which is the book you are reading.

Comment: nice interpretation +1!